# Two line datasets with different size (different labels) in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I have those two datasets:

1. about 800 values from past three days with timestamps during those days
2. 3 values from past three days with timestamp at midnight

Is it somehow possible to display those two lines in one graph, but second line respecting timestamps of line 1)? When I read documentation, there is written that all datasets should have same number of labels, but then I came across some solutions that might do what I want. But those solutions seems to be for previous version of chart.js and no longer work.

Or is the only solution to modify dataset 2) to interpolate value for every point in dataset 1)
Thanks a lot

This is the code:

```
let labels = []

let date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 10);

const tenDays = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const dateToDisplay = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  labels.push(new Date(dateToDisplay).toISOString());
  
  //array of 10 days in history from now
  tenDays.push({
    time: dateToDisplay,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  })
}

date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 10);

//array of only three days, in tenDays array that is 1st, 5th and 10th day   
const threeDays = [
  {time: date, value: 6 },
  {time: date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5), value: 4 },
  {time: date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5), value: 5 },
];

var dataset1 = {
  label: 'dataset1',
  data: tenDays.map(data => data.value)
}

var dataset2 = {
  label: 'dataset2',
  data: threeDays.map(data => data.value)
}

//create Chart
new Chart(document.querySelector('#chart') as HTMLCanvasElement, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [dataset1, dataset2],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  },
});
```

[That produces this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mzYe.png) but instead i want what is drawn green [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZztZa.png)

Comment: I have modified my question to include quick code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the actual times of the two datasets, you can just use those to place the points on to the x axis. So you could:

- keep the times in each dataset
- don't define labels
- set the type of the x axis as ["time"](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-cartesian-axis) instead of the default "category" (include the required [adapter](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters) and set other relevant properties)
- define [parsing](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#object-using-custom-properties) keys for convenience.

Then every point is placed at the correct time, where it was defined, and everything falls in place. Here's a simplified version of your code with those changes:

```js
let date = new Date();

date.setDate(date.getDate() - 10);
const tenDays = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const dateToDisplay = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  //array of 10 days in history from now
  tenDays.push({
    time: dateToDisplay,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  })
}

date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 10);

//array of only three days, in tenDays array that is 1st, 5th and 10th day   
const threeDays = [{
    time: date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1),
    value: 6
  },
  {
    time: date.setDate(date.getDate() + 4),
    value: 4
  },
  {
    time: date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5),
    value: 5
  },
];

//create Chart
new Chart(document.querySelector('#chart'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        data: tenDays,
        label: "many"
      },
      {
        data: threeDays,
        label: "few"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    parsing: {
      xAxisKey: "time",
      yAxisKey: "value",
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: "day"
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<div style="min-height:300px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure if that was what you were after, whether you have the actual times for both datasets/

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really works as I wanted. Also for my original big datasets. You are a hero!

Comment: Just one more thing. To make this work, I had to npm install chartjs-adapter-moment and have my imports like this: `import { Chart } from 'chart.js/auto';
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';` Now when I build my application, I have warning: `Warning: node_modules/chartjs-adapter-moment/dist/chartjs-adapter-moment.esm.js depends on 'moment'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies`. Can be something done about that?

Comment: chartjs-adapter-moment is just an adapter between chart,js and moment.js. So you have to also include the moment.js library, check https://momentjs.com/ for a variant that works in your environment

Comment: Yes, but I still need to use that chartjs-adapter-moment and the error comes from that package

Comment: Might be an issue with your configuration. Try to replicate the issue on a stackblitz or codesandbox.